# From file to array php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to display videos on my website. In file I have urls (separator | )
I can't do this:
Do array from text in .txt.
Get 4 random urls from array.

youtube_vids.txt

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed?v=oavMtUWDBTM|
https://www.youtube.com/embed?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ|
https://www.youtube.com/embed?v=djV11xsamQ|
https://www.youtube.com/embed?v=Tj75ArXbc914|
https://www.youtube.com/embed?v=9jK-NcRmVcw|
https://www.youtube.com/embed?v=n4RjJKhq5ho|
https://www.youtube.com/embed?v=6Ejga4kJUts|
```

I stopped here:

```
$vid_list = file('youtube_vids.txt');
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is each url on a new line or does it just appear that way due to wordwrap?

Comment: each url is on a new line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$videoArray = file('youtube_vids.txt');
$randomIndexes = array_rand($videoArray, 4);
foreach ($randomIndexes as $index) {
    echo '<iframe width="420" height="315" src="'.preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", str_replace('|','',$videoArray[$index])).'"></iframe>';
}
```

will output

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"></iframe>
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed?v=oavMtUWDBTM"></iframe>
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed?v=6Ejga4kJUts"></iframe>
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

The file() function separates the array by newline, so the | separator is unused and has to be trimmed:

```
$vid_list = file('youtube_vids.txt');
shuffle($vid_list);
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    // Trim any newline characters
    $url = trim($vid_list[$i]);
    // Then trim the 'separator'
    $url = trim($url, '|');
    echo $url . "<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is:

- First read the entire file into an array using [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)
- Then select 4 random line numbers using [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)
- And finally [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and extract URLs from the array

So your code should be like this:

```
$lines = file('youtube_vids.txt');
$rand_array = array_rand($lines, 4);

$random_urls = array();
foreach ($rand_array as $line) {
    $random_urls[] = explode("|",$lines[$line])[0];
}

// display $random_urls array
echo "<pre>";
print_r($random_urls);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$filename = "file.txt"; //Input Text File With Separators

if(file_exists($filename)) { //Check if file exists

    $myfile = fopen($filename, "r") or die("Unable to open file!"); //Reading file

    $fileData = fread($myfile,filesize($filename)); //Save file data in a variable

    $splitData = explode("|", $fileData); //Split file data using separators

    $randLinks = array_rand($splitData, 4); // Get 4 random indices from splitData array

   foreach($randLinks as $randLink) { // Foreach index
        echo $splitData[$randLink] . "<br>"; // Get url
    }

   fclose($myfile); //Don`t forget to close the file 
}
```